# How to finish proof of $ {1 \over 2}+ \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(k\varphi ) = {\sin({n+1 \over 2}\varphi)\over 2 \sin {\varphi \over 2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the identity $$ {1 \over 2}+ \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(k\varphi ) = {\sin({n+1 \over 2}\varphi)\over 2 \sin {\varphi \over 2}}$$

What I've done so far:

From geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q = {1-q^n \over 1 - q}$ for $q = e^{i \varphi}$ and taking the real part on both sides I got

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos (k\varphi ) = {\sin {\varphi \over 2} - \cos (n\varphi) + \cos (n-1)\varphi \over 2 \sin {\varphi \over 2}}$$

I checked all my calculations twice and found no mistake. Then I used trigonometric identities to get

$$ {1 \over 2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos (k\varphi ) + {\cos n\varphi \over 2 } = {\sin \varphi \sin (n \varphi ) \over 2 \sin {\varphi \over 2}}$$

> How to finish this proof? Is there a way to rewrite
>
> $\sin \varphi \sin (n \varphi )$ as
>
> $\sin({n+1 \over 2}\varphi) -  \sin {\varphi \over 2} \cos (n \varphi)
>  $?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that $2\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kθ) = \frac{\sin[\left(n+1/2\right)θ]}{\sin(θ/2)}-1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588003/prove-that-2-sum-k-1n-cosk%ce%b8-frac-sin-leftn1-2-right%ce%b8-sin%ce%b8-2)

Comment: I vote to leave open because this question is much better than the proposed duplicate.  The other was closed for missing context.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you. It was closed anyway...

Comment: @JonasMeyer No it wasn't. Sorry, the message at the top confused me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in the real part.

$$
\frac{q^n - 1}{q - 1} = \frac{e^{in\phi} - 1}{e^{i\phi} - 1}
= \frac{e^{i(n-1/2)\phi} - e^{-i\phi/2}}{e^{i\phi/2} - e^{-i\phi/2}}
= \frac{- i e^{i(n-1/2)\phi} + i e^{-i\phi/2}} {2\sin{\phi/2}}
$$
the real part is
$$
\frac{\sin ((n-1/2)\phi) + \sin(\phi/2)} {2\sin{\phi/2}}
$$
yielding the right result.

---

However, there is a simpler solution:
$$
1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^n \cos k\phi
= 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n \left(e^{i k\phi} + e^{-i k\phi}\right) = \sum_{k=-n}^n e^{i k\phi}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
e^{-i n\phi} \frac{1 - e^{i (2n+1)\phi}}{1 - e^{i\phi}}
= \frac{e^{-i (n + 1/2)\phi} - e^{i (n + 1/2)\phi}}
{ e^{-i\phi/2} - e^{i\phi/2}} = \frac{\sin((n + 1/2)\phi)}{\sin(\phi/2)}
$$

Comment: Indeed Masterful!

Comment: Thank you for your help. But how is $\sin((n-1/2)\phi ) + \sin(\phi / 2)$ equal to $\sin({n+1\over 2}\phi)$? I tried to apply the trig identity to $\sin((n-1/2)\phi ) $ and got $$ \sin \phi / 2 \sin n \phi / 2 + \sin n \phi \cos \phi / 2$$
but that doesn't yield the desired result and I don't see what other trig identity I could apply here!

Comment: look at what you try to compute: this is the sum up to $n-1$

Comment: Another two users just pointed out to me that this claim [is false](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253577/proving-sin-n-1-2-phi-sin-phi-2-sinn1-over-2-phi#comment2547316_1253577). Is it really false?

Comment: I could do it now!

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't answering your question exactly, you might like to know that there is an easier way of proving this. Just multiply both sides by the denominator of the right-hand side and then use $\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)=2$cosAsinB. You now have a telescoping series which leads quickly to the result.

Comment: probably not more quickly than my second method.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to prove is not correct. Let $n=1$, $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{3} $.