# Proving $\sin ((n-1/2)\phi) + \sin(\phi/2)=\sin({n+1 \over 2}\phi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to show that

$\sin ((n-1/2)\phi) + \sin(\phi/2)=\sin({n+1 \over 2}\phi)$

I tried to apply $\sin (x-y) = \sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y$ to it and I got

$\sin ((n-1/2)\phi) + \sin(\phi/2)=\sin \phi / 2 \sin n \phi / 2 + \sin n \phi \cos \phi / 2$

but how can I proceed from there?

Comment: Do you mean $n - \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{n-1}{2}$ above? Either way, the statement you wrote is false.

Comment: @anomaly I meant the former. It was pointed out to me like this in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1252372/54809).

Comment: it is not even true for $n = 0.$ you get on the lhs $\sin (-\phi/2) + \sin (\phi/2) = 0$ but on the rhs you get $\sin( \phi/2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the prosthaphaeresis/sum-to-product formulae. Adding the expanded forms of $\sin{(x-y)}$ and $\sin{(x+y)}$, you find
$$ \sin{(x-y)} + \sin{(x+y)} = 2\sin{x}\cos{y}, $$
and changing variables,
$$ \sin{A}+\sin{B} = 2\sin{\tfrac{1}{2}(A+B)}\cos{\tfrac{1}{2}(A-B)}. $$
Then the left-hand side of your identity is
$$ \sin{(n-\tfrac{1}{2})\phi} + \sin{\tfrac{1}{2}\phi} = 2\sin{\tfrac{n}{2}\phi} \cos{\tfrac{n+1}{2}\phi}, $$
which is not often equal to what you have on the right...

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way to rewrite it? I'm asking because this idenity was pointed out to me in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1252372/54809).

Comment: @Anna Take $n=1$, for example. The LHS is $\sin{(\phi/2)}+\sin{(\phi/2)}$, the RHS $\sin{\phi}$. These are certainly not equal.

Comment: @Anna Okay, I've had a look at that answer. I think you need to look more carefully at what sum the geometric series computes, what sum you want, and what the argument actually is (although the answer is not very clear on some points).

Comment: You are right, thank you so much for your help. I could do it!